# How to check whether grapheme is a letter?

Tags: unicode, internationalization, elixir

How do I check whether grapheme is a letter (or something that is often used in words, like hieroglyph)?

After looking through Elixir's `String` documentation the only way I see is to check whether `String.downcase` and `String.upcase` return the same string. Iff they do, then the grapheme is not something that is used in words.

This is how I do it, but surely there should be a simpler way?

```
defmodule Words do
  defp all_letters_uppercase?(string) do
    String.upcase(string) == string
  end

  defp all_letters_downcase?(string) do
    String.downcase(string) == string
  end

  defp contains_letter?(string) do
    not (all_letters_uppercase?(string) and all_letters_downcase?(string))
  end

  def single_grapheme?(string) do
    with graphemes = String.graphemes(string)
    do
      length(graphemes) == 1 and hd(graphemes) == string
    end
  end

  @doc """
  Check whether string is a single letter.
  """
  def letter?(string) do
    single_grapheme?(string) and contains_letter?(string)
  end
end
```

Update: my code doesn't work for japanese letters

```
iex(35)> Words.letter?("グ")            
false
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to check for some unicode features, one of which is `\p{Letter}`, or `\p{L}` for short. You might want to add a `\p{Mark}*`, or `\p{M}*` to also match multiple following combining diacritics. This would closely match the logic found in `String.graphemes/1`. Be sure to add the `u` modifier after the regex to enable these Unicode features. For example:

```
iex> String.match?("グ", ~r/\A\p{L}\p{M}*\z/u)
true
```

Also see http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html, section on "Unicode character properties" and http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#grapheme.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working fine:

```
defmodule Words do
  def letter?(string) do
    Regex.match?(~r/^\p{L}$/fu, string)
  end
end


iex(51)> Words.letter?("a")
true
iex(52)> Words.letter?("é")
true
iex(53)> Words.letter?("グ")
true
iex(54)> Words.letter?("aa")
false
iex(55)> Words.letter?("1") 
false
iex(56)> Words.letter?("-")
false
iex(57)> Words.letter?("") 
false
iex(58)> Words.letter?(" ")
false
iex(59)> Words.letter?("éé")
false
iex(60)> Words.letter?("a ")
false
```

Comment: Just my 2 ¢: If you want to match the whole input string you can also use the `\A` (beginning of string) and `\z` (end of string) anchors. I find `^` (beginning of line) plus `$` (end of line) plus the `f` (firstline) modifier to less clearly express the intent.

Comment: @PatrickOscity interesting, I didn't even know those anchors exist. For some reason everyone and their dog use `^` and `$`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to match multi-codepoint graphemes containing a letter and a combining character, e.g. `Words.letter?("g̈") #=> false` while your code in the question returns true.

Comment: You can use `\p{L}\p{M}*` to match any number of following combining diacritics as well.

Comment: @PatrickOscity will that do what I want? I don't think I know all functions of combining marks.

Comment: @CrabMan combining marks can be arbitrarily combined to form any combination of a character and a diacritic symbol. However, many common combinations are also available als precomposed characters. Alternatively, you could only match precomposed characters by using `String.normalize(input, :nfc)` and then only matching `\p{L}`. However I think also matching the combining marks couldn't hurt. `String.graphemes/1` also treats those as one character so you would have a close match to this logic. Edited my answer as well to include combining marks.

Comment: [This page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#grapheme) suggests using `\P{M}\p{M}*` (non-mark followed by any number of marks) to match any unicode grapheme. You want only letters, so I think `\p{L}\{M}*` (letter followed by any number of marks) should be the correct way to do it.